# Async Mock Not Working using Jest , Is there a better way or easy way as sinon.stub()

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to do mocking using **jest**, below is the pseudo code which I am trying to try, Finding really touch with **jest** . Please throw some thoughts on jest mocking. I am looking for something similar to `sinon.stub()` and which can be easily resolved using `resolve()`.

```
class ExampleService {
  static get() {
    agent.get("/examples")
  }
}
```

ExampleStore :

```
class ExampleStore {
  const examples = []
  getExamples() {
    ExperimentService.get().then((result) = > {
      this.examples = result
    })
  }
}
```

TestCases :

```
describe("ExampleStore", () = > {
it("getExamples", () = > {
  data = [{
    test: "test"
  }]
  ExperimentService.get = jest.fn(() = > {
    return new Promise((resolve) = > {
        process.nextTick(resolve(data)
        }) ExampleStore.getExamples() expect(ExampleStore.examples).toBe(data)
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jest.mock` to mock `ExperimentService.get` with your own implementation:

```
import ExampleStore from './ExampleStore'
jest.mock('path/to/ExperimentService' () =>({
  get: ()=> return Promise.resolve({test: 'test'}); 
  //get: ()=> {then: (fn)=> fn({test: 'test'})} if you don't want to mess with promises in your test
}))

describe("ExampleStore", () => {
it("getExamples", () => {
   ExampleStore.getExamples() 
   expect(ExampleStore.examples).toBe(data)
    }
  })
})
```

I'm not sure it will work with a real promise in the stub cause normally you need to wait for the promise to be resolve and return the promise from your test our use async await. Have a look on [how to handle promises](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html#content).
So either use the comment out solution to mock `get` or return the promise
in `ExampleStore.getExample`, so that you can wait for it in the test.